# Information Schema Gives different column defaults for different users logged in, with the exact same query and not sure why

Tags: sql, sql-server, runtime-error

I am running the following query as my windows user and a sql server user 'www'

```
select column_Name columnname, 
       column_default
from   staging.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS x left join staging.sys.identity_columns s on object_id('staging'+'.dbo.'+x.table_name) = s.object_id and x.COLUMN_NAME = s.name 
where  x.table_Name = 'refAirports'
```

when running as my windows user i get the following result

```
id               NULL
icao_code        NULL
iata_code        NULL
local_code       NULL
name_formatted   NULL
DateUpdated      (getdate())
DateCreated      (getdate())
```

when i run as the "www" user i get

```
id               NULL
icao_code        NULL
iata_code        NULL
local_code       NULL
name_formatted   NULL
DateUpdated      NULL
DateCreated      NULL
```

I am confused to why the two bottom columns lose the default. I am gathering it is a permission issue but unsure where to go. I will keep researching but if anyone known straight off the bat please let me know.

Comment: Meta-data visibility is determined by your permissions. Does your Windows account have [`VIEW DEFINITION`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175808.aspx) permissions?

Comment: yep thanks, the "www" user didnt have that permission. put that as answer ill select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta-data visibility is determined by your permissions. You'll need at least some permission on the securable in order for the row to be visible via the catalog views. In the case of the definition of the default, you'll also need [`VIEW DEFINITION`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175808.aspx) permission to see the `DEFAULT` defintion.